# Change Form color constantly

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, colors

I want my program to constantly change the font background color, but I want it to go smoothly so I tried to modify a Color variable `Color custom;` and use it to for the background color of the form `this.BackColor = custom;` but it doesn't work and I don't know how to make it work, here is the complete code:

```
private void Principal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Color custom;
    int contr = 0, contg = 0, contb = 0;
    do
    {
            while (contr < 255 && contg == 0)
            {
                if (contb != 0)
                {
                    contb--;
                }
                contr++;
                while (contg < 255 && contb == 0)
                {
                    if (contr != 0)
                    {
                        contr--;
                    }
                    contg++;
                    while (contb < 255 && contr == 0)
                    {
                        if (contg != 0)
                        {
                            contg--;
                        }
                        contb++;
                    }
                }
            }
            custom = Color.FromArgb(contr, contg, contb);
            this.BackColor = custom;
    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: It would work, but probably changing too fast.

Comment: when i run it it only apears semi transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, your current code doesn't work, but not because of any threading issue (although that does need to be solved).

The issue is that these lines never get hit:

```
custom = Color.FromArgb(contr, contg, contb);
this.BackColor = custom;
```

The logic in your `while` loops just don't work.

The values that you produce are the set of:

```
(0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2) ... (0, 0, 255), (0, 254, 1), (0, 253, 2) ... (0, 1, 254)
```

It then just repeated tries to produce those values, but can never break out of the `while (contr < 255 && contg == 0)` loop.

Now, assuming that's actually what you wanted then I suggest the best approach to do this is using Microsoft's Reactive Framework. Just NugGet "Rx-WinForms" and you can then write this code:

```
var ranges = new[]
{
    Observable.Range(1, 255).Select(x => Color.FromArgb(0, 0, x)),
    Observable.Range(1, 254).Select(x => Color.FromArgb(0, 255 - x, x)),
};

var query =
    ranges
        .Concat()
        .Zip(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100.0)), (x, i) => x)
        .Repeat()
        .ObserveOn(this);

var subscription = query.Subscribe(c => this.BackColor = c);
```

So `ranges` is an array of `IObservable<Color>`. Calling `.Concat()` on `ranges` turns it from `IObservable<Color>[]` to `IObservable<Color>`. The `.Zip` ties each value to a timer counting off in 10ms increments (you can change the value if you wish). Calling `.Repeat()` just repeats the loop continuously - sort of like `while (true)`. Then `.ObserveOn(this)` forces the observable subscription to be run on the UI thread.

Finally, the `.Subscribe(...)` actually runs the observable and updates the `BackColor` of the form.

The nice thing about this is that you can stop the subscription at any time by calling `.Dispose()` on the subscription:

```
subscription.Dispose();
```

That cleans up all of the threads and the timer. It's a very neat solution.

Answer (score 5):

very simple you have no delay. due to this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) add

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

all this HAS to happen on a separate thread!
or your UI will be stuck

[Check This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18702/Threading-in-NET-and-WinForms)